# Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade

Tags: xml, java-8, jaxb, eclipse-luna

i'm running eclipse luna with jdk 8 and i tried generating jaxb classes and this error kept showing, i tried multiple solutions found on internet but nothing really worked with me 
ps : i'm pointing jdk 8 not the jre.
please help!

Comment: "this error kept showing" ... WHAT error?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade @Nikolas

Answer (score 5):

Please try pointing the 'installed JRE' to JDK in eclipse->windows->preferences->installed JRE

Hope it helps you.

Comment: After what you write, you need also add this configuration to your project. Right click in project --> properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> JRE System Library ... --> Edit --> Alternate JRE : choose JDK added before to your eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Or you need to add the following dependency in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb-xjc.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

** 1 . add below dependency**

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

** 2 . Then right click on the filename.xsd  ->new ->Jaxb -> jaxB classes from schema >> then click next

> > specify the location where do you want to generate classes

-> then click finish